# Bash equivalent for SQL "1.%"

Tags: linux, bash

I'm aware than whenever I want to filter columns or... basically anything in a SQL query, i can use something like

```
Select * from table1 where name1 like "Mr.%"
```

This part

```
like "Mr.%"
```

Should grab any row in which the var name1 starts with "Mr." no matter what else is after it.

My question: Is there an equivalent for it in bash?  anything to go with grep, maybe?

Comment: So, are you searching a text file for lines beginning with "Mr."?

Comment: More especifically, lines from a text document. Yeah...

Comment: you've answered your own question there..just grep it with a regex

Comment: regex? regular expresion? I mean.. i have these 4 rows
1121;
1151;
2111;
2111;
I want only those that start with 1 to be taken or displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with grep easily:

For a file:

```
grep '^Mr\.' myfile.txt
```

For command output:

```
my-command-with-output | grep '^Mr\.'
```

EDIT: Adding an example with your example text file string:

```
grep '^1' myfile.txt
```

The example above will find any lines with starting with the number 1.